# Is DataCache's Add method 'Timeout' property sliding in nature

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

I am implementing appfabric for distributed caching , needed to know is the timeout property provided in one of the overloads is sliding or not , i.e. it increases the timeout with every usage , and how to change setting from sliding to absolute if possible

Answer (score 2):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationserver.caching.datacache.add.aspx) doesn't clearly specify, but I would expect that if it used a sliding expiry it would have discussed it in the comments, and therefore I believe it to be an *absolute* timeout.

Comment: I confirmed that all timeouts are absolute by nature. However there is a way to reset the timeout without getting item (aka DataCache.ResetObjectTimeout)